# Matlab function doesn't return vector

Tags: matlab, function, vector, output

This is a function used to evaluate a certain value *f(x)* showing diverse approximations in a vector **y**, in order to be compared. Input is a function *f* (either symbolic or function_handled), a vector of values **n**, and two values *x0* and *x*.

```
g=sym(f);
p(1)=subs(g,x0);

k=1;

for i=1:size(n) %Every iteration is an entry of y
    while k<=n(i) %Recursive evaluation of the values
        g=diff(g);
        p(k+1)=subs(g,x0)/factorial(k-1);

        k=k+1;
    end

    y(i)=double(subs(p,x));
end
```

I want to approximate *f(x)* as a polynomial a+bx+cx^2+... in every entry, and the while loop calculates a, b, c..., but **y** turns out to be a value, not a vector. Furthermore, if I try to do

```
[y1 y2]=(function)
```

A too many output arguments error is displayed. Could you tell me why doesn't MATLAB understand **y** as a vector?

Comment: What makes you think `(function)` is in any way valid matlab syntax? And please tell me you function is not called `function`. If in your function header you have `function [y1,y2]=funname(inputs)` in the file `funname.m` then you call your function as `[yout1, yout2]=funname(inputs);`

Comment: i might be tending to think that size(n) is 1

Comment: Andras:
Actual function is called vctay (value comparaison by Taylor polynomials), so I'm calling it as [y1,y2]=vctay(inputs) of course.

Agawa001:
I put an example vector, n=[0 2], explicitly and creating the vector first. I also used vectors with 7 entries.

Comment: @KonhatLeeSakurai size(n) is 1 because it is by default *size(n,1)*, use either size(n,2) or numel(n)

Comment: Thank you, @Agawa001
I just tried your advice and it worked!

Comment: @KonhatLeeSakurai no problem :) my pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Although, I honestly can't understand your function as written. Where is the (x-x0) term?

```
function y = vctay(f, n, x, x0)
    g=sym(f);

    n = sort(n(:));
    p = zeros(max(n)+1,1);

    for i = 0:max(n)
        %This is like you had it p(i) = (1/i!) f^i (x0)
        p(i+1) = subs(g, x0) / factorial(i) ;

        %This is just to save on a derivative in case it's costly
        if (i == numel(p))
            break
        end

        %This is what you had
        g = diff(g);
    end

    y = arrayfun(@(j) dot(p(1:j+1), (x - x0).^(0:j)) , n ); %This is the secret sauce. It's the sum p_0 * (x - x0)^0 + p_1 (x - x0)^1 + ...

end
```

Comment: Sorry. Thank you for your answer, but it's already solved.

The code I posted is not the full code I used, because the generation of terms for vector **y** was full written in that section.

Answer (score 0):

I  think if you know how many elements y will have the best way is to define y as a zero vector and the give the values to it one by one
or if you don't know expand the vector y every time(it's not a good idea due to time!)
like
y(i+1) = [y(i) sth];